# how to make a loop that adds up items to a list in a given condtion and giving back the sum in python?

Tags: python, list, function, random, while-loop

I use this:

```
import random
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
computer = []

def another_card_computer():
    for i in range(1):
        computer.append(random.choice(cards))

computer_score = sum(computer)
while computer_score < 17:
    another_card_computer()
computer_score = sum(computer)
print(computer_score)
```

for some reason, it just goes into an infinite loop.
I'm new to programming, python, and stack overflow so let me know if there's any more info you need here.

thanks!

Comment: You never update `computer_score` inside the `while` loop. move the [second] `computer_score = sum(computer)` line inside the loop. That said, there are other thing that can be done better.

Comment: I don't think that you actually need that for loop.  Try putting just this inside your function > `computer.append(random.choice(cards))`. Also what Buran said, You need to move the second score inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

This should work from what I can understand from the question

```
import random
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
computer = []
computer_score = 0
end = True #looping condition

while end:
    computer.append(random.choice(cards))
    computer_score = sum(computer)
    if computer_score >= 17:
        end = False
    else:
        print(computer_score)
```

if you want it as a function:

```
import random

def another_card_computer(card):
    computer = []
    computer_score = 0
    end = True #looping condition
    while end:
        computer.append(random.choice(cards))
        computer_score = sum(computer)
        if computer_score >= 17:
            end = False
        else:
            print(computer_score)
        
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
another_card_computer(cards)
```